# Why does my new Windows 10 laptop have a windows.old directory on it?

Tags: windows-10

I bought a new laptop a couple of months ago, which came with Windows 10 pre-installed (no upgrade or anything).

I just recently noticed that there is a windows.old directory in the C root.

```
C:\Windows.old>dir
 Volume in drive C is Acer
 Volume Serial Number is D261-608A

 Directory of C:\Windows.old

12/07/2015  12:22 AM    <DIR>          .
12/07/2015  12:22 AM    <DIR>          ..
12/06/2015  09:38 PM    <DIR>          Program Files
12/06/2015  09:38 PM    <DIR>          Program Files (x86)
12/07/2015  12:22 AM    <DIR>          Recovery
12/06/2015  07:56 PM    <DIR>          Users
12/06/2015  09:42 PM    <DIR>          Windows
               0 File(s)              0 bytes
               7 Dir(s)  175,413,530,624 bytes free
```

Why is it there? Was this unit or hard drive upgraded in the factory?

Comment: Because presumably you installed the `Windows Version 1511` update.

Comment: Maybe the system was reinstalled on this laptop and the `Windows.old` directory was created automatically during this installation.

Comment: the 1511 update is basically a new OS, so you this folder after upgrade.

Comment: Somebody post as an answer. :)

Comment: @Xavierjazz - Sure once the author confirm they installed that update.

Comment: There it is :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

More than likely W10 installed Windows Version 1511 update automatically, this is what created the windows.old folder.

1511 was a complete OS upgrade.